# Excel: Give each number in a text/string its own cell

Tags: excel, numbers, extract, vba

I have a text document full of 9 digit numbers. I need Excel to either read the text (`.txt`) file or a text cell and add each 9 digit number to each cell in a column.
Example text file:

```
123456789, 987654321, 213454321 / 987656789, [098752739]
```

Excel result:

```
123456789
987654321
213454321
987656789
098752739
```

Any advice?

Comment: Are you saying that your numbers are all in one row in the text file, or is it one number per row?

Comment: What does "full of 9 digit numbers" look like in the text file? Your bullet point has several 9 digit sets separated by several different characters. Can you post a more comprehensive example as a text file (use a file sharing service and post a link)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Excel feature for importing data from Text file. Ribbon tab Data -> From Text.

Answer (score 0):

From your result, with each cell containing the 9 digit number:

1. Click **Data -> Text to columns**
2. Select "**Fixed Width**"
3. You will then need to set break lines between each of your nine
   digits

> *Optional: Click "Next" to format each of the fields*

4. Finally, click "**Finish**"

You should now see each of the nine digits in a separate column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a single cell, then your task has three parts:

- read data from text file
- parse each cell
- store the results in a column

This code addresses only the second part:

```
Sub ParseData()
    Dim s1 As String
    s1 = Range("A1").Text
    s1 = Replace(s1, " ", "|")
    s1 = Replace(s1, "/", "|")
    s1 = Replace(s1, "[", "|")
    s1 = Replace(s1, "]", "|")
    s1 = Replace(s1, ",", "|")
    s1 = CleanUp(s1, "|")
    ary = Split(s1, "|")

    i = 1
    For Each a In ary
        Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
        Cells(i, 2).Value = a
        i = i + 1
    Next a
    End Sub


Public Function CleanUp(sIN As String, sep As String) As String
    Dim temp As String, temp2 As String, i As Long, CH As String
    temp = sIN
    While Left(temp, 1) = sep
        temp = Mid(temp, 2)
    Wend

    While Right(temp, 1) = sep
        temp = Mid(temp, 1, Len(temp) - 1)
    Wend

    temp2 = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(temp)
        CH = Mid(temp, i, 1)
        If temp2 = "" Then
            temp2 = CH
        ElseIf CH <> sep Then
            temp2 = temp2 & CH
        ElseIf Right(temp2, 1) <> sep Then
            temp2 = temp2 & CH
        End If
        Next i
    CleanUp = temp2
End Function
```

**NOTES:**

The code replaces the various field separators with a single pipe.  The data is then split using the pipe.  The resulting array is then stored in cells:

[image]